# Xcode - Could not find test host

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I am receiving an error message when I try to use Xcode 8's Convert Wizard. After trying install KIF Framework.

Here is the error message:

> Could not find test host for PresentrTests: TEST_HOST evaluates to "/Users/mymacbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-akrziiobrmqfliboqlgonjeyvquu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApplication.xctest/MyApplication"

Answer (score 345, accepted):

1. Select the Xcode project in the lefthand browser.
2. Click on your test target in the Project's General tab.
3. Under "General" select your appropriate host application under "Testing".

Comment: Do you have an idea as to how the project got into the state where the target was not properly selected?

Comment: @Stefan Did you rename your project recently?

Comment: @Sam honestly, I do not remember, but I do not think I did.

Comment: If you rename your project name then follow these steps:
1. follow @spfursich first 3 steps which was helpful for me (thnx @spfursich)
2. Select Test target
3. Select Build Setting
4. Search Product Name
5. Rename to your <new name>
6. Go to your test.swift file 
7. edit this line: testable import <new name>

Comment: @spfursich what about latest Xcode? That option is still there under General in Target but  Xcode defaults with nothing selected and my only option is "None"

Comment: Click your Target on the top of Xcode near the Stop button and choose Edit Scheme, then ensure your target has the Test checkbox selected.

Comment: Hello @spfursich, i am facing the issue with a project that has multiple targets, and when following ur solution, I cant find Testing under general. I can see it under the target but not when selecting any of the targets, but only when selecting the test target. Any idea